# Building jsonpath with Scala Play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a simple json structure like this:

```
{
  "type": "type",
  "id": "id",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "system": "system1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "system": "system2",
      "value": "value2
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the identifier value where system is `system1`. I can't rely on the order of the identifier array so I actually need to check the value of `system`.

I constructed this jsonpath for lookup: `$.identifier[?(@.system == 'system1')].value`, and it works.

Now my question is, how do I use this jsonpath with the Scala Play framework? I know there is a `JsPath` class in it but I've only seen examples with straight paths, none with conditions for sybling nodes like the one I need. And I can't seem to construct a `JsPath` instance out of a string. What gives me hope is that the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#JsPath) says `JsPath` is analogous to XPath in XML, which does have the condition-on-sybling-node functionality.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself ?

Comment: Since I use jsonpath elsewhere in my project, I tried to stick to this approach but now I see I have to let it go. Of course I can do what I want easily if I convert the json to a Scala object... It just would've been beautiful with the jsonpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analogous doesn't mean identical, and `JsPath` doesn't offer conditional path.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val js = Json.parse("""{
  "type": "type",
  "id": "id",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "system": "system1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "system": "system2",
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}""")

(js \ "identifier").validate[Seq[JsObject]].flatMap[String] { jsonIdentifiers =>
  jsonIdentifiers.filter { idObj =>
    (idObj \ "system").toOption.contains(JsString("system1"))
  }.headOption.flatMap(obj => (obj \ "value").toOption) match {
    case Some(JsString(id)) =>
      JsSuccess(id)

    case _ =>
      JsError("Missing id")
  }
}

// => JsSuccess(value1,)
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming there are no conditional paths in JsPath. And thank you for the example code, although I think I'll look for a simpler solution.